# regular expression for only two alphabets

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression validator in aspx code which is only for two alphabets **A** or **C** .
I have tried the below regex which is not working.

```
 "^[AC]+$"
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Your problem is not clear as it is at the moment. Please elaborate and provide more examples

Comment: give a sample input please

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches a string that consists of at least one (`+`) `A` and/or `C`, but possibly more. It will match `A` and `C`, but also `AAA` or `ACACAC` etc.

If you want to match only a single letter, remove the `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Answer (score 0):

quoting your question

> which is only for two alphabets A or C

I can only guess that you either want `A` or `C`.

In that case use a regular expression `^[AC]$`

This will only allow A or C. Feel free to ask for any clarifications